# Conversion of Date in Java

Tags: java, date, date-format

Why if I convert a date from milliseconds to days, and then back, from days to milliseconds, this date change?

for example:

```java
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = format.parse("2012-06-02");
System.out.println(date);
Long dateAsDays = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(date.getTime());

System.out.println(
    new Date(
        TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(dateAsDays)
    ) );
```

will be printed:

> Sat Jun 02 00:00:00 GMT+03:00 2012
>
> Fri Jun 01 03:00:00 GMT+03:00 2012

How I can save the day of the month in this conversion? And why this code is not working properly?

Comment: For Date/Time issues, you should use [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) project, it provides easy ways to handle Date, Time and Timestamp operations.

Comment: If you have the choice, use JODA instead of the built-in Java date facilities, which are more than a little broken.

Comment: Thanks for the advice to use Joda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date becomes less accurate when you get it in days. You are in GMT+3, so 12:00 GMT is 3:00 for you. From the [TimeUnit class reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#convert%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29):

> convert
>
> public long convert(long sourceDuration,
>                       TimeUnit sourceUnit)
>
> Convert the given time duration in the given unit to this unit. **Conversions from finer to coarser granularities truncate, so lose precision**. For example converting 999 milliseconds to seconds results in 0. Conversions from coarser to finer granularities with arguments that would numerically overflow saturate to Long.MIN_VALUE if negative or Long.MAX_VALUE if positive.
>   For example, to convert 10 minutes to milliseconds, use: TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(10L, TimeUnit.MINUTES)

Comment: The usage of this method lead a problem that arises in example. Guess, usage of 'TimeUnit' tool does not allow the required transformation.